# How to divide an heavy sql query in multiples queries?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run the following query in order to retrieve the id of the geospatial location ( polygon ) for each data ( points). But I have too much data and it takes too much time henceforth my queries runs forever ( I think it just crashes ).

When i put limit 200000 it works but i have more data 3 millions, but only 1.1 millions are concerned my my request.

I use PostgreSQL 15.5.

**Not working code :**

````sql
UPDATE alerts
SET ogc_fid = subquery.ogc_fid
FROM (
    SELECT a.uuid, ct.ogc_fid
    FROM alerts a
    JOIN competences_territoriales ct ON ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(a.location::geometry, 4326), ct.wkb_geometry)
    WHERE ct.competence = 'GN'
    
) AS subquery
WHERE alerts.uuid = subquery.uuid
AND alerts.ogc_fid IS NULL ;```
````

**Working code :**

```sql
UPDATE alerts
SET ogc_fid = subquery.ogc_fid
FROM (
    SELECT a.uuid, ct.ogc_fid
    FROM alerts a
    JOIN competences_territoriales ct ON ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(a.location::geometry, 4326), ct.wkb_geometry)
    WHERE ct.competence = 'GN'
    limit 200 000
    
) AS subquery
WHERE alerts.uuid = subquery.uuid
AND alerts.ogc_fid IS NULL ;
```

Comment: Please don't use images, just plain text. Besides that, when a query is slow, you'd better find out why. The DDL for all tables and indexes is useful, just like the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this SQL statement. All in plain text

Comment: I think your query is your bottleneck. More information like how many points are you comparing against, the DB version and plugins like PostGIS would also be helpful. Also, running traces against your database queries would go a long way to help diagnose why the query churns for so long.

Comment: Please post the query, avoiding adding images.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your answer. I use Postgis 15.5 and i have 3 millions data in alerts but only 1 millions are concerned by my query, and 3000 locations ( polygon ).

Comment: Thank you Frank i wont put images in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database might have internal support for iteration. But a universal solution can be accomplished with itertools:

```
import itertools

limit = 200000
offset =  itertools.count(start=0, step= 200000)

cursor = conn.cursor()

while True:
    query = your_query.format(limit, next(offset))
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(result) > 0:
        do_something(result)
    else:
        break
```

It’s important to note you must update the query you have in your images to have both a limit and offset, e.g. “UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE .. LIMIT .. OFFSET .."

Comment: Oh okay ! Im gonna try that idea  :D